# pandas.series.split(' ',expand =True) With Column Names

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, split

I have a Pandas Data Frame with two string columns, which I would like to split on space, like this:

```
 df =
        A                                   B
        0.1  0.5  0.01 ...                    0.3  0.1  0.4 ...
```

I would like to split both these columns and form new columns for as many values, which result out of the split.

So, the result:

```
df =
       A1      A2.    A3  ...               B1        B2        B3
       0.1     0.5   0.01 ...               0.3       0.1       0.4
```

Currently, I am doing:

```
 df = df.join(df['A'].str.split(' ', expand = True)
 df = df.join(df['B'].str.split(' ', expand = True)
```

But, I get the following error:

```
 columns overlap but no suffix specified
```

This is because I guess columns names of 1st and 2nd split overlap?

So, my question is how to split multiple columns by providing column names or suffixes for multiple splits?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) for columns names by splitted column:

```
df = df.join(df['A'].str.split(expand = True).add_prefix('A'))
df = df.join(df['B'].str.split(expand = True).add_prefix('B'))
print (df)
              A            B   A0   A1    A2   B0   B1   B2
0  0.1 0.5 0.01  0.3 0.1 0.4  0.1  0.5  0.01  0.3  0.1  0.4
```

Another idea is use list comprehension:

```
cols = ['A','B']
df1 = pd.concat([df[c].str.split(expand=True).add_prefix(c) for c in cols], axis=1)
print (df1)
    A0   A1    A2   B0   B1   B2
0  0.1  0.5  0.01  0.3  0.1  0.4
```

And for add all original columns:

```
df = df.join(df1)
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael, I have other columns in the dataframe as well apart from these two columns. I should have mentioned in the question. Your solution is not working for now as it is for me. In the 1st case, suffix gets added to all the other columns. In the second case, all the other columns get deleted from the dataframe. Is there a way I can take into account the fact that I have other columns in my dataframe as well?

Comment: @SumitSidana - Are good last `))` in first solution? there is no only last `)` , so added prefixes to all columns?

Comment: How would you replace by a name instead of a prefix when doing the split ?

Comment: the general solution for these three comments is to: 1) collect all of the column names at the beginning `col_list=df.columns` 2) iterate over the column list at the beginning 3) drop the original columns